# Does UnmappedResourceHandler work for library versioning?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, versioning, omnifaces, unmappedresourcehandler

I am trying out the `UnmappedResourceHandler` in OmniFaces, originally I had all my resources under a directory structure like:

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- default
 |         `-- 1_0
 |              |-- css
 |              |    `-- style.css
 |              |-- img
 |              |    `-- logo.png
 |              `-- js
 |                   `-- script.js
```

The `UnmappedResourceHandler` doesn't work with the versioning, instead this works:

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- default
 |        |-- css
 |        |    `-- style.css
 |        |-- img
 |        |    `-- logo.png
 |        `-- js
 |             `-- script.js
```

I haven't read anywhere that it doesn't work so I am wondering am I missing something?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mentioned in the [javadoc](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.0/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/UnmappedResourceHandler.html) and [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler).

> And the following CSS file reference (**note: the library is not supported by the UnmappedResourceHandler! this is a technical limitation, just exclusively use name**):
>
> ```
> <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
> ```

The technical limitation is that it's otherwise not possible to relatively reference resources from inside the CSS file. When using libraries, the path `/default` would be moved to query parameter `?ln=default` and then the CSS file would be looking for relative image references in the wrong relative folder `/resources/css` instead of `/resources/default/css`.

You've 2 options:

1. Manually append the version to the query string.

   ```
   <h:outputStylesheet name="default/css/style.css?#{app.version}" />
   ```

   You could even write another custom resource handler for that.
2. Use the file name based versioning.

   ```
   WebContent
    |-- resources
    |    `-- default
    |        |-- css
    |        |    `-- style.css (this is a folder!)
    |        |         `-- 1_0.css
    |        |-- img
    |        |    `-- logo.png (this is a folder!)
    |        |         `-- 1_0.png
    |        `-- js
    |             `-- script.js (this is a folder!)
    |                  `-- 1_0.js
    :
   ```

   It's only uglier.

Regardless, feel free to just remove the `/default` folder in the end.

Comment: sorry, I had read that but didn't know that the library attribute was related to the version number